# Workaround for CronSequenceGenerator Last day of month?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, cronexpression

Ok so here it is I  want to schedule a task to run on last day of every month on 10:10 AM.My cron expression is

```
0 10 10 L * ?
```

Now the problem is [CronSequenceGenerator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) is throwing NumberFormatException for 'L' value.This means Spring's CronSequenceGenerator does'nt support this kind of expression.How to do this in any other way (workaround).I don't want to use quartz or Does spring's gonna support this in new releases.

Here is full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "L"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.getRange(CronSequenceGenerator.java:324)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.setNumberHits(CronSequenceGenerator.java:297)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.setDays(CronSequenceGenerator.java:275)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.setDaysOfMonth(CronSequenceGenerator.java:266)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.parse(CronSequenceGenerator.java:239)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.<init>(CronSequenceGenerator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger.<init>(CronTrigger.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger.<init>(CronTrigger.java:44)
    at com.hcdc.coedp.datantar.scheduler.SchedulerUtil.start(SchedulerUtil.java:75)
    at com.hcdc.coedp.datantar.scheduler.SchedulerUtil.changeTrigger(SchedulerUtil.java:106)
    at com.hcdc.coedp.datantar.scheduler.SchedulingService.scheduleTransfer(SchedulingService.java:70)
    at com.hcdc.coedp.datantar.scheduler.Scheduler.schedule(Scheduler.java:107)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

Update:

Following is my scheduling method

```
 /**
    * Schedule a task {@link Task} with a specified cron expression.
    * @param task {@link Task}
    * @param cronExpression cron expression to be applied must be a vaild one.
    * @param taskName
    * @return 
    */
     public String start(Task task, String cronExpression, String taskName) {
        CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(cronExpression);//line 2

        CronSequenceGenerator generator = new CronSequenceGenerator(cronExpression, TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
        List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<>(5);
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            currentDate = generator.next(currentDate);
            dateList.add((currentDate));
            System.out.println("Next Exceution times are" + currentDate);
        }
        ScheduledFuture sf = tps.schedule(task, trigger);

        //TODO Save this scheduled future with a specific task name.
        ContextHolder.schduledFutureMap.put(taskName, sf);
        return cronExpression;
    }
```

And on line 2 it throws NumberFormatException when I pass specified cron expression.

Comment: I looked around a bit, and it seems that L is actually supported. How are you defining the job? Annotation? You should probably add this to your question.

Comment: Great. Could you also paste the relevant code that calls the `start()` method? I'm sorry about this, but I really think using `L` should work.

Comment: Actually that won't affect the output you could test it in a simple main program just pass cron expression with 'L' in start method You will get the exception.

Comment: @Magnilex: I'm looking at the [code](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.java) and I can't see why you think it must work.

Comment: @sinuhepop Well done. I actually didn't research too much, and thought that L was part of the Crontab pattern. What I really wanted to make sure though was that OP really posted a correct String, which he convinced me that he does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature is not in [standard cron expression syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Special_characters). So probably Spring will never implement it. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.java), I can't see any *surgical* solution extending `CronSequenceGenerator`. So why you just don't use Quartz since it's a [particular feature](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html)?

Depending on your exact need, you could implement your own [Trigger](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/Trigger.html#nextExecutionTime%28org.springframework.scheduling.TriggerContext%29). Something like:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TriggerContext;

public class LastDayOfMonthTrigger implements Trigger {

    private final LocalTime time;

    public LastDayOfMonthTrigger(LocalTime time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext ctx) {
        Date last = ctx.lastScheduledExecutionTime();
        LocalDate date = last == null ? new LocalDate() : new LocalDate(last).plusDays(1);
        LocalDate lastDay = date.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
        return lastDay.toDateTime(time).toDate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,And I could'nt use quartz because It demands architecture- level refactoring..."They'll kill me"....And I will try your CustomTrigger idea It seems like it will work...

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround I would schedule the execution for all dates

```
0 10 10 * * ?
```

and checked the actual date in the scheduled method

```
public void scheduledTask() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (c.get(Calendar.DATE) == c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It would work, but I would only schedule the method for the possible last days of month, something like day 27-31.

Comment: Yes, I think it would be some optimization

Comment: But you said you wanted the last day of every month

Comment: Sorry I have put myself incorrectly..."not only last days"....I want to schedule monthly and day could be any day of month..But problem arrives only for last days...i.e feb 29th..Also my cron expression is dynamic for single task.Check update..

Answer (score 2):

Optimized version which runs only on the last day of a month:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 55 23 28-31 * ?")
public void doStuffOnLastDayOfMonth() {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (c.get(Calendar.DATE) == c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE)) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution:

Generate one month of data. The program should run on the first day of the next month to ensure that all data for the entire month is captured.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 1 * ?") // runs on the first day of each month

public void doStuffOnFirstDayOfMonth() {

    Date now = DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -1); // "now" is now on the last day of the month

}
```