# Custom trigger with spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, cronexpression

I'm trying to use a last day of the month custom trigger which I found in SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079289/workaround-for-cronsequencegenerator-last-day-of-month/18079545#18079545)

How do I refer to the LastDayOfMonthTrigger in the xml? I want to replace the corn expression with this custom trigger.
Below is how I have my jobs context configured.

```
<batch:job id="someJob">
    <batch:step id="someStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="someTask"/>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
<bean id="someScheduler" class="com.my.org.scheduler.RunScheduler">
    <constructor-arg ref="someJob"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="jobLauncher"/>
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
   <task:scheduled ref="someScheduler" method="run" cron="0 0/5 * * * ?"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
0 0 0 L * ?
```

This cronexpression will trigger your scheduler on last day of every month at 12:00am [You can verify it here](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Comment: thank you for the response, but this will only work if I have quartz scheduler. The **L** is not implemented in spring scheduler which is what I'm using.