# Cron Expression is not working for last day of the month

Tags: java, spring

I want to schedule a task to run on last day of every month at 10:10 AM.
The cron expression is `0 10 10 L * ?`

Now the problem is `CronSequenceGenerator` is throwing `NumberFormatException` for 'L' value. This means Spring's `CronSequenceGenerator` doesn't support this kind of expression. But if I am passing only passing numeric it is working fine.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "L"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.getRange(CronSequenceGenerator.java:324)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.setNumberHits(CronSequenceGenerator.java:297)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.setDays(CronSequenceGenerator.java:275)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.setDaysOfMonth(CronSequenceGenerator.java:266)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.parse(CronSequenceGenerator.java:239)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.<init>(CronSequenceGenerator.java:81)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger.<init>(CronTrigger.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger.<init>(CronTrigger.java:44)
at com.hcdc.coedp.datantar.scheduler.SchedulerUtil.start(SchedulerUtil.java:75)
at com.hcdc.coedp.datantar.scheduler.SchedulerUtil.changeTrigger(SchedulerUtil.java:106)
at com.hcdc.coedp.datantar.scheduler.SchedulingService.scheduleTransfer(SchedulingService.java:70)
at com.hcdc.coedp.datantar.scheduler.Scheduler.schedule(Scheduler.java:107)     
at main.Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

Comment: Please edit your post using the format tools to make clear that you question is.

Comment: @satyam: Please close this thread if you got the answer..

Answer (score 20):

**Update for Spring 5.3**

Spring [now supports the following syntax](https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions) to run on the last day of the month

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 L * *") // last day of the month at midnight
```

**Original answer:**

This Schedule runs on the last day of the month an 10:10AM:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 10 28-31 * ?")
public void doStuffOnLastDayOfMonth() {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (c.get(Calendar.DATE) == c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE)) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Downside is that that this run on each day in between the 28th and 31st, however it works because of the `if` statement. If you use `L` sadly spring complains with a `NumberFormatException`

Comment: this is perfect solution with minimum complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link
[Cron Maker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Give your expression in the text box

> 0 10 10 L * ?

Answer (score 1):

The last day of the month is not supported by Spring. See [`CronSequenceGenerator`'s javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is another possible approach, depending on what you want to do:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 1 * ?") // runs on the first day of each month
public void doStuffOnFirstDayOfMonth() {
    Date now = DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -1); // "now" is now on the last day of the month
}
```

I use this to generate statistics for a month of data. The routine should run on the first day of the *next* month to be sure to capture all data of the full *previous* month.

While this does not answer the question in the sense of having a Cron Expression for the last day of the month, it still can be a solution for jobs which need to run for a full month and this as soon as possible after the month has come to an end.

Comment: Nice approach that although it doesn't solve the original question... helps in several cases.

Answer (score -1):

Expression syntactically correct with your condition: `0 10 10 L 1/1 ? *`

And this is workaround that you could be interested: [Workaround for CronSequenceGenerator Last day of month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079289/workaround-for-cronsequencegenerator-last-day-of-month)

Comment: I am putting the cron expression in a properties file and using that place holder in  @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.val}") in spring boot application i am getting the above mentioned problem