# Issue with Spring Cron job scheduling?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron

I am trying to run this job in spring but i am getting an error

My intention is to run the job last Friday of every month

```
@EnableScheduling
@Service
 public class TestSchedular {
    @Scheduled(cron= "0 0 0 ? * 6L")
   public void schedular() {
    System.out.println("Cron Job");
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'schedular': For input string: "6L"
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cron Expression is not working for last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445395/cron-expression-is-not-working-for-last-day-of-the-month)

Answer (score 1):

Your cron expression ("0 0 0 ? * 6L") is invalid.

Spring's CronSequenceGenerator class has a method isValidExpression(String expression) which takes the cron expression and returns a boolean.

You could use that to check your Cron expression.